# Weirdness adding a lightning component to a JS Array

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a component that looks like this:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="invoiceItems" type="Object[]"  access="public"/>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.invoiceItems}" var="i" indexVar="x">
        {!i}
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

The controller looks like this:

```
({
init : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    $A.createComponent(
                "c:Line_Item",
                {
                    "invoiceItems" : cmp.getReference("v.invoiceItems")
                },
                function(newItem){
                    var items = cmp.get("v.invoiceItems");
                    items.push("v.invoiceItems", newItem);
                    cmp.set("v.invoiceItems", items);
                }
    );
}
})
```

And the dynamically created component looks like this:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="invoiceItems" type="Object[]"  access="public"/>
    TEST ME
</aura:component>
```

When the "init" function is called and the first line item is added to the array it's adding the view label as well.  Every iteration/row of the invoiceItem array looks like this:

```
v.invoiceItems
TEST ME
```

when it should just look like this:

```
TEST ME
```

I `console.log`'ed the invoiceItems array and it looks like this:

```
[]
0
:
"v.invoiceItems"
1
:
componentConstructor
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array[0]
```

Why is it adding the label as the first element of the array and then the actual object as the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess it's this line of code:

```
items.push("v.invoiceItems", newItem);
```

`Array.prototype.push` is a standard JS function, not Lightning. If you include multiple arguments, each one is added to the array. So you have instructed to add the string `"v.invoiceItems"` and then also add `newItem`. Change it to:

```
items.push(newItem);
```